# issues calculating rowwise maximum

Tags: r, dplyr

suppose I have a tibble dat below, what I would like to do is to calculate maximum of (`x 2`, `x 3`) and then minus `x 1`, where x can be either a or b. In my real data I have more than 3 columns, so something like 2:n (e.g., 2:3) would be great. tried many things, seems not working as I wanted them to, still struggling with the string vs column name thing..

```
dat <- tibble(`a 1` = c(0, 0, 0), `a 2` = 1:3, `a 3` = 3:1, 
`b 1` = rep(1, 3), `b 2` = 4:6, `b 3` = 6:4)


foo <- function(x = 'a')
{
  ???
}
```

end result:

```
if x == `a`

c(3, 2, 3)

if x == `b`

c(5, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution 1

This solution uses only base R. The idea is to define a function (`max_minus_first`) to calculate the answer. The `max_minus_first` function has two arguments. The first argument, `dat`, is a data frame for analysis with the same format as the OP provided. `group` is the name of the group for analysis. The end product is a vector with the answer.

```
max_minus_first <- function(dat, group){
  # Get all column names with starting string "group"
  col_names <-  colnames(dat)
  dat2 <- dat[, col_names[grepl(paste0("^", group), col_names)]]

  # Get the maximum values from all columns except the first column
  max_value <- apply(dat2[, -1], 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)

  # Calculate max_value minus the values from the first column
  final_value <- max_value - unlist(dat2[, 1], use.names = FALSE)

  return(final_value)
}

max_minus_first(dat, "a")
# [1] 3 2 3

max_minus_first(dat, "b")
# [1] 5 4 5
```

#### Solution 2

A solution using the `tidyverse`. The end product (`dat2`) is a `tibble` with the output from each group (`a`, `b`, ...)

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  gather(Column, Value, -rowid, -ends_with(" 1")) %>%
  separate(Column, into = c("Group", "Column_Number")) %>%
  gather(Column_1, Value_1, ends_with(" 1")) %>%
  separate(Column_1, into = c("Group_1", "Column_Number_1")) %>%
  filter(Group == Group_1) %>%
  group_by(rowid, Group, Value_1) %>%
  summarise(Value = max(Value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(Final = Value - Value_1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-starts_with("Value")) %>%
  spread(Group, Final)
dat2
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   rowid     a     b
# * <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     3     5
# 2     2     2     4
# 3     3     3     5
```

#### Explanation

1. `rowid_to_column()` is from the `tibble` package, a way to create a new column based on row ID.
2. `gather` is from the `tidyr` package to convert the data frame from the wide format to long format. I used `gather` twice because the first column of each group is different than other columns in the same group. `ends_with(" 1")` is a `select` helper function from the `dplyr`, which select the column with a name ending in `" 1"`. Notice that the space in `" 1"` is important because `"1"` may select other columns like `a 11` if such columns exist.
3. `separate` is from the `tidyr` package to separate a column into two columns. I used it to separate the `Group` name and column numbers in each `Group`.
4. `filter(Group == Group_1)` is to filter rows with `Group == Group_1`.
5. `group_by(rowid, Group, Value_1)` and then `summarise(Value = max(Value, na.rm = TRUE))` make sure the maximum from each `Group` is calculated.
6. `mutate(Final = Value - Value_1)` is to calculate the difference between maximum from each `Group` and the value from the first column. The results are stored in the `Final` column.
7. `select(-starts_with("Value"))` removes any columns with a name beginning with `"Value"`.
8. `spread` from the `tidyr` package converts the data frame from long format to wide format.

#### Solution 3

Another `tidyverse` solution, which similar to Solution 2. It uses `do` to conduct operation to each `Group` hence making the code more concise.

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  gather(Column, Value, -rowid) %>%
  separate(Column, into = c("Group", "Column_Number")) %>%
  group_by(rowid, Group) %>%
  do(data_frame(Max = max(.$Value[.$Column_Number != 1]),
                First = .$Value[.$Column_Number == 1])) %>%
  mutate(Final = Max - First) %>%
  select(-Max, -First) %>%
  spread(Group, Final) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   rowid     a     b
# * <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     3     5
# 2     2     2     4
# 3     3     3     5
```